# How to use Query and where?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I have some issues with Queries and Where operators.

So entity is:

```
@Entity('clients')
@Index(['id', 'slug'], { unique: true })
export class Client extends BaseEntity {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    id: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    slug: string;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)', onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)' })
    updatedAt: Date;

    @Column({ default: false })
    isVisible: boolean;

    @OneToOne(() => PublicFile, { eager: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    logo?: PublicFile;
}
```

Controller method:

```
@Get()
    async getClients(@Query() query): Promise<Client[]> {
        return await this.clientsRepository.find({
            select: ['id', 'slug', 'title', 'isVisible', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'],
            where: { isVisible: query.visible ? Like('true') : Any([true, false]) },
            relations: ['logo'],
            order: {
                updatedAt: 'DESC'
            }
        });
    }
```

Then I trying to get clients list with url: `/clients?visible=true` and I get empty array

And when I get `/clients` I get empty array either

Is there proper way to use Query and where?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that I always use in my projects.

I use conditional [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) to "build" the query dynamically. See [this](https://www.sanity.io/blog/how-to-conditionally-build-an-object-in-es6) for more information.

In addition:

1. Removed `select` from query since is the same as a `*`. You have a relation, so why not select those fields too?
2. Removed `await`. As far as I can see you want to return a Promise of `Client[]`: the `find` method is already returning the correct type.

```js
@Get()
async getClients(@Query() query): Promise<Client[]> {
    return this.clientsRepository.find({
        where: {
            ...(query.visible !== undefined && { isVisible: query.visible }),
        },
        relations: ['logo'],
        order: {
            updatedAt: 'DESC'
        }
    });
}
```